# no se muestra la imagen en el dispositivo movil en react native

Tags: react-native

este es el codigo del archivo app.js :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Platform,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      Image
    } from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends Component<{}> {
     render() {
     const image ='https://i.imgur.com/E2PbxmA.jpg'
     return (
     <View style={{width: 200, height: 200}}>
       <Image
         style={{width: 150, height: 150}}
         source={{uri: image}}
       />
      </View>
      );
     }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },

     });
```

El problema es que no se muestra la imagen en el device

Comment: Intenta usar https y no http, intenta con este link: https://i.imgur.com/E2PbxmA.jpg

Comment: ya lo intente y sigue igual, lei que ese problema de http y https es en IOS y que en android no deberia dar, pero no se que pasa que no muestra nada.

Comment: El problema también podría ser el estilo de tu contenedor, específicamente el tamaño, aplicale al `View` también `style={{width: 150, height: 150}}` y asegurate de que si tienes mas contenedores padre tengan un tamaño mayor al de la imagen.

Comment: lo modifique así y aún tiene el mismo problema

Comment: render() {
    const image ='https://i.imgur.com/E2PbxmA.jpg'
    return (
      <View style={{width: 200, height: 200}}>
        <Image
          style={{width: 150, height: 150}}
          source={{uri: image}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

Comment: Podrías modificar tu pregunta y añadir mas código al menos el mínimo para poder replicar esto y poder ayudarte

Comment: esta bien ahora lo modifico y copio todo el archivo .js

Comment: ahi esta el código, podrias ayudarme por favor, no encuentro la solucion

Comment: Funciona bien, no te muestra algún error en la consola?

Comment: El `<{}>` se utiliza en `flow` o `typescript` que claro no estas utilizando y probablemente te provoque un error de sintaxis pero fuera de eso funciona bien

Comment: ningun error en consola, la app se instala en el device, corre y todo pero no muestra la imagen

Comment: encontraron solucion ?????....por que tengo el mismo problema. Con el request muestra la imagen pero no se que pasa con el uri.....